# What would I miss, if I don't use any authentication in django and login the user using django query filter with a manually hashed password

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I have seen the default user authentication and custom user uathentication in django, I would like to know what would I be missing if I just login a user by using a normal query like, ____.objects.get(password = ______, email = ______) and just hash the password stored in the model column.And store the login details in session and clear them on logout.  Would it ruin the security altogether or is it something else I wouldn't get which is found in the normal django authentication?

Answer (score 0):

No problem to write your own login backend, but only if you know what you are doing and what to take care of! Much easier and faster way is to modify Django stuff: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/